# Programmatically bypass firewall c++

Tags: c++, http, firewall, windows-firewall

I'm sending raw HTTP packets to a server, will adding a program to the list of exceptions enable me to do that? If so, Is there any way for me to automatically(without user interactions) add my program to the list of exceptions in the firewall?

Comment: The Windows firewall is typically used to block incoming traffic, not outgoing traffic. It's very rare that *sending* traffic to a remote server requires any change to the firewall rules.

Comment: @deviantfan I'm not sure that this is about raw sockets... it could be about TCP sockets, where OP is sending "raw HTTP," as in, not using wininet or any other third party library to handle the request.

Comment: @cdhowie I should read more carefully, I know...

Comment: Think about it... the purpose of a firewall is to let a user (or they system administrator) block/control what can come in and/or go out... if a firewall _is_ set up to block outgoing traffic from malicious/undesirable/whatever software, they're not going to make it easy to allow a program to add itself to the "allowed to send list".  So I'd hope the answer is "no".

Comment: If your application is running eleveated, [sure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff956128\(v=vs.85\).aspx)